# Jargon professionnel : "suivi de la capacité"

Tags: vocabulaire, informatique, jargon

Dans mon milieu professionnel (industrie des technologies de l'information), on peut être amené à user de l'expression "suivi capacitaire" pour exprimer un "suivi de la capacité de quelque chose" (par exemple, au sujet de la capacité de stockage d'un serveur). Or il me semble que l'usage soit incorrect, car l'adjectif [*capacitaire*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/capacitaire) se rapporte au suffrage (voir sur CNRTL) et donc plutôt à une capacité légale qu'à une capacité mesurable en volume.

Un adjectif plus correct, dérivé du substantif "capacité", moins jargonisé si je puis me permettre, vous vient-il à l'esprit ?

Comment: Pardon de répondre à une question par une question, mais : quelle est la raison pour laquelle tu cherches un substitut à la très claire expression *suivi de [la] capacité* (que tu as toi-même employé pour te faire comprendre de nous) ? Le *la* entre crochets est optionnel à mon avis.

Comment: En effet, naturellement, je dis _suivi de [la] capacité_, mais ce n'est pas le cas de mes collègues, chez qui j'entends _suivi capacitaire_. Et cela titille mes oreilles depuis un certain temps, d'où ma question ici.

Answer (score 3):

Peut-être « suivi quantitatif » : un peu comme « volumétrique » mais ce dernier est déjà utilisé pour autre chose.

Ou peut-être « suivi des niveaux » comme s'il s'agissait d'une rivière qui risquait déborder.

Ou « suivi du stockage ».

Answer (score 2):

J'ai souvent entendu : "Quel est le taux d'occupation" du serveur XXX ?

> Suivi du taux d'occupation

... pourrait peut-être convenir.

On pourrait aussi employer un mot technique :

> Suivi du remplissage

Comment: en effet, il s'agit d'une bonne alternative. Je continue de me demander s'il n'existe pas une version "courte" en un adjectif... dans le milieu, les gens seraient rapidement tentés de transformer "suivi du taux d'occupation" en "suivi occupatoire", ou que sais-je d'autre...

Comment: @Nomaru J'ai complété ma réponse, on utilise généralement ce terme pour les liquides en fûts ou en cuve, mais cela n'a rien de choquant pour un serveur dont on représente souvent les disques par des cylindres.

Answer (score 1):

It’s hard to find a positive adjective that doesn’t sound like it’s describing the accuracy or efficiency of “le suivi” instead of describing its purpose.

Maybe that’s why your co-workers felt obliged to “invent” a new definition of “capacitaire” to use in this non-legal context because they found it to be more neutral and less ambiguous than other adjective options.

> “[Suivi fonctionnel](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=suivi%20fonctionnel)”

could be an option because it does seem to be a bit more neutral than other positive adjectives and the "[Linguee](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=suivi%20fonctionnel)" site gives examples of it being used both to describe the “quality” and the “purpose” of “le suivi.”  It could, however, still be seen as ambiguous and I'm not even sure if the notion of "fonctionalité" exists in your industry.

Perhaps you will have to do your co-workers one better and actually invent a new word, such as the following (although here are [3 examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rendementaire%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb) of its prior use):

> “Suivi *rendementaire*”

Comment: Interesting thoughts :) and indeed, _suivi fonctionnel_ does not seem natural and rather describes, as you say, the "quality" of the "suivi". And as to the invention of new words, well, I don't feel ready :D

Answer (score 0):

« suivi volumétrique » qui me vient à l'esprit, ferait-il l'affaire ?

Avec un substantif :

> suivi de contenance

Comment: Merci pour l'avis mais hélas non. On entend _volumétrique_ plus souvent pour parler de _volumes d'opérations_ (ce qui me paraît aussi incohérent).